# Xamarin.iOS Design Suggestion

Tags: xamarin.ios, autolayout, constraints, landscape, portrait

New to Xamarin world.
Need a suggestion on how to design a screen.
I need to design a login screen which has a 1 dropdown, 2 text boxes and 1 button - all vertically centre aligned.
It shall run on both portrait / landscape mode on all iPhone and iPads
as well.
I had faced problem in landscape mode. Background image gets squeezed and content gets hidden and it doesn't have a scrollbar.
Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resize the controls when the device rotate to landscape via code.

`ViewWillTransitionToSize()` will be fired when the device is rotated. You can resize the controls here, like this:

```
    public override void ViewWillTransitionToSize(CGSize toSize, IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator coordinator)
    {
        base.ViewWillTransitionToSize(toSize, coordinator);

        coordinator.AnimateAlongsideTransition((IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) => {

            if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait || UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown)
            {
                //Update UI
            }

            if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft|| UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight)
            {
                //Update UI
            }

        }, (IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) => {
            //Transition Completion
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin for a response, I'll try this solution and will let you know.

Comment: Its Working.  I've used "override void WillAnimateRotation" this method to detect if device rotates. Thanks